# Two questions about adding custom content to config.fish

Tags: command-line, terminal, fish

I have a question about the **Fish** (Friendly Interactive SHell), so I hope somebody can help me out.

Basically I'd like to customize the fish_greeting message.  I can easily get it to say anything I'd like, but I'm having problems setting colors for different lines.  Please note that I found some instructions from other sites which said to put this inside of `config.fish`, rather than in `/functions/fish_greeting`.  I couldn't tell you why, but I followed those instructions nevertheless.

This copy of the command I've been working on should make what I just said more clear:

```
### Set Fish_Greeting to... ###
set fish_greeting '
    (set_color green) "              Hi Ev!          "
    (set_color blue) "      Welcome to the Terminal! "
'
```

I'm obviously doing it wrong because when I type `fish` to test it out, I'm met with:

```
 

(set_color green) "              Hi Ev!          "
(set_color blue) "      Welcome to the Terminal! "
```

I know that looks like I've formatted something wrong here, but I assure you, those extra empty lines are shown on the terminal.

Does anybody know of a way I could do this easily?  Is this something that's much too complicated for what its worth?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would make the fish greeing into a function, not a variable

```
function fish_greeting
    set_color green; echo "              Hi Ev!           "
    set_color blue;  echo "      Welcome to the Terminal! "
    set_color normal
end
funcsave fish_greeting
```

Your attempt is not working due to the single quotes: you don't get command substitution inside single quotes.

And if it's a function, then ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_greeting is the appropriate place to store it.